# How to understand what a function will do without being near a computer?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm studying for an exam and came across this question.

```html
def subsets(lst):
   if len(lst)==0:
       yield []
   else:
       for tail in subsets(lst[1:]):
           yield tail
           yield [lst[0]]+tail

print(list(subsets([1,5,3])))
```

We're supposed to write down what will be the output without using a computer.

Now this is an iterator, and putting list before the function will put whatever the program yields into a list.

I get into the third recursion and I have difficulty following what will happen, since we're running a loop on the the result of the recursion.

Are there any techniques/ways to draw some sort of tree/table to help me better understand the output of this snippet of code?

Comment: It generates all subsets...

Comment: Well, you take your example `[1,5,3]` and go line by line using pen and paper and see what happens until the end.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm sure OP gets that but that doesn't explain what the *exact* output of the program will be i.e. the order in which the subsets are listed. That'll require more thought (self-recursive generators can be really tough to reason about).

Comment: @Tagc thank you,  the list output does indeed need to be in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

The program generates all subsets. This is because in the `for` loop, it "emits" all `subsets` of the tail and there is a version with the "head" and without".

I would - in order to analyze it functionality - make an analysis in reverse. It is clear that for every recursive call, we drop one element: the "head" so to speak. And the recursion ends when there are no heads left: in that case we emit the empty list.

Now we move one level up: what if we feed it a list with one element? The recursive call will obviously emit the empty list (as we just have demonstrated), and here we emit two version: one with the head and one without the head. So if we feed it `[a]`, we will get two versions: `[]` and `[a]`.

Now inductively one can say that when we get the list of all subsets `S` for a list `L=[x2,x3,x4,...,xn]`, then the list of subsets for `L'=[x1,x2,x3,...,xn]` is the list of subsets `S` of `L` together with the list of subsets where we add `x1`.

About the order of things, since in each recursive `for` loop, we first `yield` a version without the "head", it is clear that the empty list will be yielded first. Next, since we are in the head, is the version with the real head. The next element will be the one where the second head is in, and no other elements. Thus it is like binary counting. For the list `[x1,x2,x3,x4]`:

```
binary  result
0000    []
0001    [x1]
0010    [x2]
0011    [x1,x2]
0100    [x3]
0101    [x1,x3]
0110    [x2,x3]
0111    [x1,x2,x3]
1000    [x4]
1001    [x1,x4]
1010    [x2,x4]
1011    [x1,x2,x4]
1100    [x3,x4]
1101    [x1,x3,x4]
1110    [x2,x3,x4]
1111    [x1,x2,x3,x4]
```

If you want it the opposite way, you should yield without and with in a separate `for` loop:

```
def subsets(lst):
   if len(lst)==0:
       yield []
   else:
       for tail in subsets(lst[1:]):
           yield tail
       for tail in subsets(lst[1:]):
           yield [lst[0]]+tail
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are fully capable of writing the code yourself, you will be okay with the exams. Try to code it yourself, put "prints" in functions to see what exactly is happening there.

Comment: You also have to be able to explain *why* it works. That are two different things. Some students struggle wiith the latter.

Comment: True. In fact if you can code it yourself you know how it works, its about your english after that isnt it

Answer (score 0):

First, I identify all of the local variables the function needs in each iteration.  This includes the parameters, locally created variables, and (occasionally) a temporary value that arises in a recursive call.

For this function, I get

```
return bookmark
lst
tail
temp for subsets(lst[1:])
```

Your two return points are line 9 (main) and line 5 (recursion).

Now start hand-simulating the initial call with pencil and paper.  Most of what you're doing is to maintain the call-stack storage and values.  We start with the main program:

```
list(subsets([1,5,3]))
```

Every time you call the routine, "push" those four variables onto the stack (values or reserved storage; just make it a nice box).  Every time you return, "pop" them back off (use your eraser).

Now make the call.  The stack now looks like this:

```
return: line 9
lst:    [1, 5, 3]
tail:   None
temp:   None
--------------------
list(subsets([1,5,3]))
```

This puts you at the top of the function.  Work your way through, line by line.  len(lst) is not 0, so jump to the **else**.  You immediately hit the expression **subsets(lst[1:])**, which will give a series of values to **tail** on the current stack chunk -- when we return.  For now, push the next call onto the stack:

```
return: line 9
lst:    [5, 3]
tail:   None
temp:   None
--------------------
return: line 9
lst:    [1, 5, 3]
tail:   None
temp:   None
--------------------
list(subsets([1,5,3]))
```

Again, len(lst) is not 0, and we hit the **else**.  Push that call onto the stack.  In fact, while we're at it, let's skip ahead one call, and also push the one after that:

```
return: line 9
lst:    []
tail:   None
temp:   None
--------------------
return: line 9
lst:    [3]
tail:   None
temp:   None
--------------------
return: line 9
lst:    [5, 3]
tail:   None
temp:   None
--------------------
return: line 9
lst:    [1, 5, 3]
tail:   None
temp:   None
--------------------
list(subsets([1,5,3]))
```

NOTE: In the processing below, I have taken a short-cut, treating the generator somewhat as if it were returning a list instead of yielding individual results.  This is to keep the answer short enough to understand.  In reality, the run-time system keeps bouncing up and down the levels, dealing with only one returned leaf-node list at each call.

*Now* len(lst) == 0, so we **yield []** and return to the calling program.  The yielded result becomes the value of that **temp** variable I made up.

```
return: line 9
lst:    [3]
tail:   None
temp:   []
--------------------
return: line 9
lst:    [5, 3]
tail:   None
temp:   None
--------------------
return: line 9
lst:    [1, 5, 3]
tail:   None
temp:   None
--------------------
list(subsets([1,5,3]))
```

Now we iterate through that list, **tail** taking on each value ... but there aren't any, so we yield two lists in turn:  [] and [3] to the previous call.  For convenience, I'll represent those as a list in **temp**.

```
return: line 9
lst:    [5, 3]
tail:   None
temp:   [[], [3]]
--------------------
return: line 9
lst:    [1, 5, 3]
tail:   None
temp:   None
--------------------
list(subsets([1,5,3]))
```

The current call has lst as [5, 3].  **tail** will take on two values: [] and [3].  For each of those, we will yield that list, both with and without prepending the element **lst[0], which is **5**.

```
[]
[5]
[3]
[5, 3]
```

At each of those, we return to the previous call, with a stack state of

```
return: line 9
lst:    [1, 5, 3]
tail:   None
temp:   [[], [5], [3], [5, 3]]
--------------------
list(subsets([1,5,3]))
```

Finally, iterating through *this* level will produce the expected output:

```
[[], [1], [5], [1, 5], [3], [1, 3], [5, 3], [1, 5, 3]]
```